# I am trying to popup text when hover on any icon without using javascript or anything else?

Tags: html, css

In CSS is there any way to popup text while hovering on icon that too without using any javascript?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please see [ask] for tips on asking questions which get fewer downvotes. [Edit] your question to show what research you've done into the issue and what attempts you've made to solve the issue based on that research.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the `:hover` puesdo-class with puesdo-elements to do it.

```css
.hover-me::before{
  content: 'YOU HOVERED!!';
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  display: none;
}

.hover-me{
margin-top: 2em;
}

.hover-me:hover::before{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class='hover-me'>Hover Me!</h1>
```